# This RegEx is not working when I use RegEx Class

Tags: ruby, regex

I have written the following code

```
policy="Policy: SCW000359-18\nAB & A Abcdef"
p policy[/(?<=Policy:) \w+-\w+/]
```

It works so perfectly, it prints the following result

```
" SCW000359-18"
```

But I have to receive the regular expression as a string parameter so I have written the following code

```
p policy[/#{Regexp.quote("(?<=Policy:) \w+-\w+")}/]
```

But it's returning nil. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is RegEx? There is a popular term regex, and a Ruby class `Regexp`, but I have never heard of RegEx. Is is something like FedEx?

Comment: Regular expression is what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegExp.quote` will quote the metacharacters in the regexp, so it is going to search for the literal string: `(?<=Policy:) \w+-\w+`, which obviously is not in your search string `Policy: SCW000359-18\nAB & A …`.

In this case you should not quote the regex string and instead use:

```
 Regexp.new('(?<=Policy:) \w+-\w+')
```

[Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Regexp.html#method-c-new)

Comment: Don't you mean "...will escape the metacharacters..."? Note also the errant "k" in the last of the words. Will delete this comment.

Comment: removed the typo! Thanks for mentioning it…